# Last Bootstrap Radio-Element ist not shown

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have the following form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='..//styles/styles-scale1-ma.css' />
    
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h1 class="display-5">Scale 1</h1>
        <h3 class="text-muted mb-5">Subtitle 1</h3>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              Item 1
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title mb-4">Question</h5>
              <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-0" value="0">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-0">
                    Answer 0
                    </label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-1" value="1">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-1">
                        Answer 1
                    </label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-2" value="2">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-2">
                        Answer 2
                    </label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-3" value="3">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-3">
                        Answer 3
                    </label>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-4" value="4">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-4">
                        Answer 4
                    </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='../script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

At the moment there is no script, but I use Bootstrap for the styles. My problem ist, that the last Radio isn't showing up. But it doesn't seem that there is a problem with the last element itself. If I delete it, the same problem appears with the fourth radio.
What did I forget? I googled, but nobody seems to have the same issue.

Thanks,
Tobi

Comment: You code looks ok at my end.

Comment: I thought so too, so there must be a problem with bootstrap, right?

Comment: Can you post your whole html code?

Comment: I just posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could nest the input and label tag in Div element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='..//styles/styles-scale1-ma.css' />
    
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h1 class="display-5">Scale 1</h1>
        <h3 class="text-muted mb-5">Subtitle 1</h3>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              Item 1
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title mb-4">Question</h5>
              <div class="form-check">
        <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-0" value="0">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-0">
                    Answer 0
                    </label>
        </div>
        <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-1" value="1">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-1">
                        Answer 1
                    </label>
        </div>
        <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-2" value="2">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-2">
                        Answer 2
                    </label>
        </div>
        <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-3" value="3">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-3">
                        Answer 3
                    </label>
        </div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-4" value="4">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-4">
                        Answer 4
                    </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='../script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Group radios on the same horizontal row by adding `.form-check-inline` to any `.form-check`. please refer more here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#inline

Your radio button code should be as below.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-0" value="0">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="1-1-0">Answer 0</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-1" value="1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="1-1-1">Answer 1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-2" value="2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="1-1-2">Answer 2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-3" value="3">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="1-1-3">Answer 3</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-4" value="4">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="1-1-4">Answer 4</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To list radio button  just place your inputs between the Div attribute. This would provide radio button for each element.Here I have provided the code for your reference.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='..//styles/styles-scale1-ma.css' />
    
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h1 class="display-5">Scale 1</h1>
        <h3 class="text-muted mb-5">Subtitle 1</h3>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              Item 1
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title mb-4">Question</h5>
              <div class="form-check">
              <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-0" value="0">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-0">
                    Answer 0
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-1" value="1">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-1">
                        Answer 1
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-2" value="2">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-2">
                        Answer 2
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-3" value="3">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-3">
                        Answer 3
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="scale1-ma" id="1-1-4" value="4">
                    <label class="form-check-label mb-3" for="1-1-4">
                        Answer 4
                    </label>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='../script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```